# Is it possible to import all modules within a package from a a different directory in python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

I am using Python 3.8. I have a directory structure like this:

```
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test2.py
└── test.py
```

Contents of test2:

```py
def x():
   print(999)
```

Contents of __init__.py :

```py
from test2 import *
```

Contens of test.py:

```py
import package
package.x()
```

Running test.py gives the following error:

```py
  from test2 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test2'
```

I want test.py to work as expected. Please help.

Comment: I think it  should be `from .test2`

Comment: To import test 2 
Maybe try this:

import package.test2

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks. It fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the @hjpotter92 said, the problem is in the `__init__.py` file because the importation should be:

```
from .test2 import *
```

And then to use the functions inside `test2.py` in `test.py` you just need something like this:

```
import package
package.x()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) you can find more information about this topic and some advices.

**EDIT**:

The main reason why you have to import using `from .test2 import *` and not `from test2 import *` is because `test2` is inside what Python calls a `package` (you called the directory with the same name) and it's supposed to use outside the same package(in `test.py`), otherwise you wouldn't need to use `.` to import it.

For instance, if you have a structure like this:

```
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test2.py
|   └── test3.py
└── test.py
```

In `test3.py` you can do: `from test2 import x` because is in the same `package` (named package)

`.` represents to the package where the module is in, for example, if you wanna import in `test.py` without using `__init__.py` you should do this: `from package.test2 import *`

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Could you please explain why 'from test2 import *' doesn't work. It works from IDLE